# Execute bitbake recipe discarding what sstate_cache is

Tags: yocto, bitbake, build-system

I have a yocto project where I added some recipes and some of the functions in them are crucial when building (the functions consist inly some links creations, some files "equilibristics"). Although when first build all is done and the sstate_cache is saved to shared/sstate_cache so that those recipes are mentioned executed. When I make some changings on building system, also delete some of the built files or the hole build dir and rerun the build, bitbake does not execute the recipes.
The only solution is to:

```
bitbake -c cleanall <list_of_my_recipes_to_be_rerun>
```

So I have to explicitly clean the cache to tell bitbake to rerun them.

So my questions are: 
Is there some way to explicitly set the recipe to be executed no matter what the shared cache saved on it?
Or maybe save the state locally in the build dir?
Or maybe tell bitbake not to save state for the recipe?

Answer (score 3):

Easy way:

```
$ bitbake <recipe> -C unpack
```

This builds recipe but forces unpack to rerun, which means everything else has to rerun too.

However if the recipe doesn't work with sstate then that is a problem with your recipe.

Answer (score 3):

You could set BB_DONT_CACHE = "1" in the recipe, rerun the recipe with the -C option, or make the task checksum depend upon these things which you're changing so it automatically rebuilds when you change them. You could also just clean the recipe and then use the --no-setscene to bitbake.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some way to explicitly set the recipe to be executed no matter what the shared cache saved on it?

To force a recipe to run regardless of what is in the shared-state cache (or anything else),
pass the `-f | --force` option to the bitbake command, e.g.

```
bitbake -f [other_options...] recipe_name ...
```

See the [bitbake commmandline options](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#usage-and-syntax) in the manual.